# Wix v4 bal Condition Как правильно использовать оператор сравнения "<"?

Tags: wix

Подскажите пожалуйста, как корректно использовать оператор "<" в следующем коде?
Ошибка:

> Символ "<" с шестнадцатеричным значением 0x3c недопустим в значениях атрибутов XML

```xml
<util:FileSearch
          Id="HAL.DLL"
          Path="[WindowsFolder]System32\hal.dll"
          Result="version"
          Variable="NT603HALVER"
          Condition="VersionNT = v6.3" />
        <bal:Condition
            Condition="NOT ((VersionNT = v6.3) AND (NT603HALVER < v6.3.9600.17031))"
            Message="This application requires S14 Update (KB2919355) for Windows 8.1 / Server 2012 R2.">
        </bal:Condition>
```

Comment: Скорее всего экранировать как-то надо. Но это не точно.